# Downgrade MySQL 5.7 to 5.1 in CentOS 6

Tags: centos, yum, mysql

I previously installed MySQL built-in 5.1 and it worked well. Today, I followed [this article](https://www.if-not-true-then-false.com/2010/install-mysql-on-fedora-centos-red-hat-rhel/) and installed 5.7. Unfortunately, my VM has limited ram (512mb) and 5.7 cannot be started. I would like to downgrade MySQL to my working version 5.1.

I did remove 5.7 by using `yum remove mysql` successfully. But then:

```
# yum download mysql
No Match for available package: mysql-5.1.73-8.el6_8.i686
Nothing to do
```

If I run `yum install mysql`, it reinstall 5.7 version again. How can I reinstall mysql 5.1?

#### Log from file mysqld.log.rpmsave

```
170620 23:48:04  InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
170620 23:48:10  InnoDB: Shutdown completed; log sequence number 0 34058928
170620 23:48:10 [Note] 
170620 23:48:10 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid ended
170620 23:54:27 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /var/lib/mysql
170620 23:54:27 [ERROR] Can't read from messagefile '/usr/share/mysql/english/errmsg.sys'
170620 23:54:27  InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 8.0M
170620 23:54:27  InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
170620 23:54:27  InnoDB: Started; log sequence number 0 34058928
170620 23:54:27 [ERROR] /usr/libexec/mysqld: unknown variable 'innodb_large_prefix=true'
170620 23:54:27 [ERROR] Aborting

170620 23:54:27  InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
170620 23:54:32  InnoDB: Shutdown completed; log sequence number 0 34058928
170620 23:54:32 [Note] 
170620 23:54:32 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid ended
```

#### Log from file messages

```
Jun 21 00:46:03 vpn1UgoVPNcom kernel: Out of memory: Kill process 31276 (mysqld) score 162 or sacrifice child
Jun 21 00:46:03 vpn1UgoVPNcom kernel: Killed process 31276, UID 0, (mysqld) total-vm:126948kB, anon-rss:98224kB, file-rss:8kB
```

There is no such file mysqld.err , also Mysqld.log is empty

#### Attempting to start MySQL 5.7

```
[root@vpn1UgoVPNcom home]# service mysqld start
/usr/bin/mysqld_safe: line 196:  9475 Killed                  nohup /usr/sbin/mysqld --basedir=/usr --datadir=/var/lib/mysql --plugin-dir=/usr/lib/mysql/plugin --user=mysql --log-error=/var/log/mysqld.log --pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid --socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock < /dev/null > /dev/null 2>&1
MySQL Daemon failed to start.
Starting mysqld:                                           [FAILED]
```

Comment: `limited ram`? I am running MySQL 5.5 with 256MB RAM. It is not fast but it works. Have you looked at the error log `/var/log/mysql.err`?

Comment: I have uploaded some log. Please help to review.

Comment: MySQL 5.1 was end-of-lifed in 2013. Instead of rolling back to a long-dead version of MySQL, you'd be better off trying to fix the memory usage problem or upgrading to the next logical release, like MySQL 5.5.

Answer (score 2):

I ran the following commands and it's back to 5.1 and running well now:

```
yum remove 'mysql*'
yum install mysql-server-5.1*
service mysqld start
```

Answer (score 1):

That article has you add the Oracle community MySQL repos, whose packages obsolete the stock packages. You need to disable that repository first (`yum-config-manager --disable mysql57-community` or edit the files in /etc/yum.repos.d) and then you can install the stock 5.1 version from the stock repos again.

Comment: I tried your command and the output is:
# yum-config-manager --disablerepo mysql57-community
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Error getting repository data for mysql57-community, repository not found

Comment: Whoops, small typo. Use the flag `--disable`, not `--disablerepo`.  I edited my answer to correct that command.

Answer (score -1):

You can download the RPM from the below link and install it using RPM install command:

```
rpm -ivh mysql-5.1.73-8.el6_8.x86_64.rpm
```

Download Link:
https://centos.pkgs.org/6/centos-x86_64/mysql-5.1.73-8.el6_8.x86_64.rpm.html

Comment: rpm -ivh mysql-5.1.73-8.el6_8.i686.rpm
error: Failed dependencies:
        mysql-libs = 5.1.73-8.el6_8 is needed by mysql-5.1.73-8.el6_8.i686

Comment: Try this please `rpm -Uvh --force mysql-5.1.73-8.el6_8.i686.rpm`.